# Android: download arrow doesn't appear

Tags: android, notifications

i'm trying to develop an app that shows video and you can download it on your mobile
the app is working perfectly, but my problem is that the download arrow doesn't appear in notification bar.

I'm using download manager class.

Here's my method:

```
public void downloadFileFromUrl(String url, String fileName, DownloadManager downloadManager) {

    String filePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "BlueNet";

    try {

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/BlueNet",fileName);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(
               DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

    idDwnldMng= downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    }

    catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you missing the permission:

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: no, I'm using it  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: are you sure the server responses video file by the given url, not redirects or returns an error?

Comment: the video file is downloaded perfectly, but the problem is that the arrow doesn't appeaing while the video is downloading, about the visibility i'll try it

Comment: when i remove it, nothing happened at all, same problem

Comment: @M.Honi try to add this permission as well `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />`

Comment: but this permission will  hide the arrow right?
i want to show it

Comment: The last thing I can assume, you android version doesn't support this feature

Comment: no, I download apps, Movies, music,...etc from Internet and the arrow is appearing..... and my android version is 4.4.2...API:19